# Need to convert single text column to a single row and then split the row based on the pattern

Tags: bash

I am very new to the bash programming and need to convert a single text column to a single row and then separate the characters in the row based on the pattern.

I have text document with the column, which has one letter with six digits
in each line:

```
a111111
b222222
c333333
d444444
e555555
```

I need to transform the column above into the following row:

```
'a111111','b222222','c333333','d444444','e555555'
```

Could someone please advise how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach:

```
sed -r 's/^|$/\x27/g' file | paste -sd,
```

sed adds the single quotes at the beginning and end of each line, and paste joins the line together with commas

Or, print a comma for each line, and when you're done  back up 1 character and overwrite the last comma with a space:

```
awk '{printf "'\''%s'\'',", $0} END {printf "\b \n"}' file
```

Comment: Thank you so much glenn jackman. Both suggested by you approaches do work! I vote for the option 1 because option 2 does look very cryptic for me. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` with `printf`:

```
awk -v ORS=, 'NR>1{printf "%s", ORS} {printf "\x27%s\x27", $0}' file
```

`\x27` prints a single quote.

For the 2nd record onwards it will prints `ORS` (which is set to comma) at start and then the quoted line will be printed.

**Output:**

```
'a111111','b222222','c333333','d444444','e555555'
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and for suggestion anubhava. A while ago I saw you used option with awk ORS.Could you please provide it as well.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks anubhava. Your updated answer does not produce the desired outcome though. After running awk -v ORS=, '{printf "\x27%s\x27", (NR==1)? $0 : ORS $0}' file, I am getting: 'a111111'',b222222'',c333333'',d444444'',e555555' Does it mean the "\x27%s\x27" should have a single quotes, instead of double ones?

Comment: Ah that's right, I have updated the awk command now to take care of it.